# WordPress 5.5 AutoUpdate schedule

Tags: updates

I use the new WordPress built-in auto-update feature for plugins. I want to update my plugins as soon as there is a new release but today i checked my websites ond most of the plugins have the notice "Automatic update scheduled in 2 days". Is it possible to change the WordPress built in auto-update schedule or where is this option set?

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a way to change the frequency that is why I use [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) for updating WordPress, plugins, themes and language files. Anyway I prefer to do it scheduled on a defined time e.g. nightly.

With a Cronjob you can execute as many times a day you want. I use this commands:

```
cd /folderToWordpressInstallation 
    && wp core update && wp plugin update --all 
    && wp theme update --all 
    && wp language core update 
    && wp language plugin update --all 
    && wp language theme update --all
```

wp command must be available on your web hosting. It can be downloaded here https://wp-cli.org/. Either use /path/wp or add path to wp command to your PATH variable within hosting environment. Then path prefix is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for Feedback. Now it is better formatted. I wrote also commands. Because with && multiple commands are concatenated to execute updates for WordPress itself, plugins, themes and so on.

Comment: Just the obligatory - _"be careful with these commands"_ as they will include major, minor and patch releases. Generally it's best to test anything that's not just a patch update before release.

Comment: Oh yes, if you like to update only to minor versions, use **--minor** parameter for `wp core update` command